# Invalid types for array

Tags: c++, types

I'm trying to run next code and I get the invalid type error for j inside the loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)  //steps
        {
        j[i]=0;
        for (int j = 0; j < Particles; j++)  //Particles
            {
             u = randnum(0,1);
             dr = pow( pow( a, 1-alph ) + u * (1-alph)/B, 1/(1-alph));
             phi[j] = randnum(0,M_PIl);
             pre_x = x [j];
             pre_y = y [j];
             x[j] = pre_x + cos(phi[j]) * dr;
             y[j] = pre_y + sin(phi[j]) * dr;
            while( (sin(A * x[j]) + Delta * sin(C * x[j])/2) * h + H < y[j])
                 {
                 u = randnum(0,1);
                 dr = pow( pow( a, 1-alph ) + u * (1-alph)/B, 1/(1-alph));
                 phi[j] = randnum(0,M_PIl);
                 x[j] = pre_x + cos(phi[j]) * dr;
                 y[j] = pre_y + sin(phi[j]) * dr;
                 }
                 j[i] = j[i] + cos(phi[j]);
             }
                 myfile<<j[i]<<endl; //Outputs array to txtFile
        }
        myfile.close();
```

I have checked other questions with the similar title but title doesn't match to my case. Exact statement for error is:

```
invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
j[i] = j[i] + cos(phi[j]);
```

Comment: j is an int. you can't use it as an array. You get an error because it's wrong.

Comment: It seems you have two different things both named `j` - an array (the declaration of which is not shown in your code) and a loop index. Give them different names.

Comment: What is `j` declared as BEFORE the outer loop?   That information will explain the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Line 3 I see `j[i]=0;` which leads me to assume `j` is an array declared above what we see here. However you then ghost `j` using that as your int in your for loop. Towards the bottom you then do `j[i] = j[i] + cos(phi[j]);`. However, in this scope `j` isn't your array, **its an int of  the iteration num of that loop**.

Rename the array or the int in your for loop

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have declared j as an array. And also in **for (int j = 0; j < Particles; j++)** you are declaring another j as integer.
at this point j becomes local integer j , so it doesn't recognize previous array j.
try to renamed the array to something else or rename the **for (int j = 0; j < Particles; j++)** to 
**for (int k = 0; k < Particles; k++)** or something similar